# Photoshop Javascript make pdf Presentation with unsaved open document

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

how to make the pdf presentation with unsaved open document ? 
below code only work for saved document with file path

```
var inputFiles =[];   
for(var a =0;a< app.documents.length;a++){  
    inputFiles.push(app.documents[a].fullName);  
    }  
var outputFile = File("~/Desktop/JavaScriptPresentation.pdf");   
var options = new PresentationOptions;  
options.presentation = true;   
options.view = true;  
options.autoAdvance = true;   
options.interval = 5;   
options.loop = true;   
options.transition = TransitionType.RANDOM;  
app.makePDFPresentation(inputFiles, outputFile, options);   
alert("Presentation file saved to: \n" + outputFile.fsName);
```

Comment: Use JSPDF for generating PDF it is a great library.

Comment: @RahulDudharejiya this question is about Photoshop's ancient-JS-based-API, not JS in general.

Answer (score 0):

As per [The official documentation](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2015.pdf) the [makePDFPresentation](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2015.pdf#page=49&zoom=auto,-155,454) function has been deprecated as of Photoshop CS4, so the only real recommendation here is "don't ask on Stackoverflow, ask on the Adobe [Photoshop Scripting forum](https://forums.adobe.com/community/photoshop/photoshop_scripting)", which is the first place you want to ask questions about using any of Adobe's product APIs.